# Why are Cyrillic letters outputted as question marks when I parse an HTML with JSOUP?

Tags: java, character-encoding, jsoup

I am trying to parse the HTML of a website and I use jsoup for the task.

When I use the parse method Jsoup class, the outputted cyrilic letters of the HTML are presented as question marks(?).

Below is my code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new URL(url).openStream(), "UTF-8", url);
doc.outputSettings().escapeMode(EscapeMode.xhtml);
System.out.println(doc.toString());
```

When I run the above code, cyrilic letters from the HTML are outputted as follows:

```
<meta name="description" content="Watch, ?? ???? ?? 195.00??. ??????? ?? ANALOG - DIGITAL. ?? ?????? ??????? Casio. ?????????? ???????? ?? CASIO">
```

The problem seems to be related to jsoup and how it reads the UTF-8 encoded HTML because when I parse download the HTML with a BufferedReader it saves outputs the cyrylic letters correctly.

I would like to have the cyrilic letters outputted as they should be and not like question marks. How can I do that?

Comment: Maybe your console is currently unable to display those characters.

Comment: I tried saving the HTML to a .txt file, and the cyrilic letters are still question marks there.

Comment: Question marks instead of characters is a strong indication for an encoding issue. So it is either reading with the wrong enconding, writing with the wrong encoding or the tools used do not support the encoding.

Comment: The encoding in the html file is as follows:
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

Comment: Try using https://validator.w3.org to see encoding settings sent back to client. Sometimes server sends HTTP header with different encoding information than from `<meta>`. For instance if you take a look at https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.pl%2F you will see `Error: Internal encoding declaration utf-8 disagrees with the actual encoding of the document (iso-8859-2)`.

Comment: Hello Pshemo, I tried using the validator and it indeed returned many errors, but non of them resembled the one in your comment. Also non of the incidents were related to charsets and UTF-8. Most of them were due to unclosed tags.

Comment: This may be a problem of this one site as I see they mix cyrillic characters with other letters so encoding of this fragment may be wrong. Did you try any other cyrillic page like this? ```String url = "https://mail.ru";
  Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new URL(url).openStream(), "UTF-8", url);
  doc.outputSettings().escapeMode(EscapeMode.xhtml);
  System.out.println(doc.select("meta[name=description]"));``` Your code works for me.

Comment: I figured out what my problem was. It was not anything in the code, neither anything special in the html. The problem in my case was with the text file encoding of the class itself. This encoding can be changed by right clicking on the class and then selecting properties. All I had to do was change the text file encoding from Cp1252 to UTF-8. Afterwards I ran the program and everything worked as it should.